# Distorção de imagem com CSS?

Tags: css, css3

estou em um projeto onde a designer responsável me deu o seguinte layout pra passar pra HTML + CSS:

[image: O que tenho que implementar]

Alguém sabe me dizer se tem uma forma de fazer isso com CSS3? Pensei inicialmente em um box-shadow, mas não tem como implementar da forma que foi feito com essa imagem. E essa distorção nas bordas inferiores também não conheço uma forma de fazer. Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FN38d/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma solução CSS2 (para uma CSS3, veja o link do @Sergio):

Crie uma imagem com a sombra:

[image: sombra]

CSS

```
.sombra {
   width:530px;
   padding: 0 10px 20px 10px;
   background: #fff url('/sombra.png') center bottom no-repeat;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="sombra"><img src="/foto.jpg" alt="" width="530" height="300"></div>
```

Veja funcionando no **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3mfvG/)**

Comment: Opa! Obrigado! Vou tentar. E quanto à distorção nas bordas inferiores? A imagem aparenta estar um pouco dobrada... É possível também?

Comment: @PedroVinícius Atualizei a resposta, veja o JSFiddle que eu pus. A imagem em si não está distorcida, mas a curva da sombra dá essa impressão.

Answer (score 8):

Sim, isso é possível com CSS3. O Bacco já deixou uma alternativa, com uma imagem de fundo, aqui fica com CSS3:

A ideia é criar elementos virtuais com efeito de sombra por detrás da imagem. Esses elementos virtuais levam uma rotação e colocam-se por trás da imagem. Exemplo de CSS em baixo, e exemplo com a [imagem transparente aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/NF3B2/), para poder vêr o que se passa por trás.

```
.lifted:before, .lifted:after {
    bottom:15px;
    width:50%;
    height:5%;
    max-width:300px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    box-shadow:0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.lifted:before {
    left:5px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-3deg);
    transform:rotate(-3deg);
}
.lifted:after {
    right:5px;
    left:auto;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(3deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(3deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(3deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(3deg);
    transform:rotate(3deg);
}
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/R7K2p/)